# How to live stream a video in C++

Tags: c++, http, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I've found some other solutions on the internet to achieve this but I didn't find anything which actually does live streaming. 
My case is I'm constantly getting the video data in my buffer now I want to stream that video data. I don't have a file already saved at some location.
I know it's a little broad question. I'm not asking for the code. But just an idea how should it be done.

Comment: You actually need a video decoding library to decode stream to frames and a graphics library (directx, qt similar) to display frame. In case no decoding library is available, you need to implement one by yourself by understanding the specifications of library.

Comment: @P0W I've not used live555 yet but can you make sure if it can be used exactly for my purpose ?